# Checkbox with inverted binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two entities, `Customer` and `User` as follows:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Id", TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Id { get; set; } // nvarchar(20)
    [Required]
    public string GivenName { get; set; } // nvarchar(100)
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; } //  nvarchar(100)
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I have a simple strong typed view for editing a customer, and I want to add to the view a check-box with following logic - the check-box should be selected, when there is at least one user for that customer and the `Locked` property of the first user is set to `false`. I just can't find a way to accomplish this. What's the proper way to do this in MVC? And how the processing method (the `[HttpPost]Edit`) receives the value of this check-box, currently it simply gets the `Customer` object?  Should I create an additional model for this view? Or there is another way?
Anticipating this question I should say that I'm taking care that there wont be more than one user for a customer.

## Updates:

1. I've added a view model for customer and updated the edit view and the controller to work with this model:

   ```
   public class CustomerViewModel
   {
     public Model.Data.Customer  BaseCustomer    { get; set; }

     public bool                 HasActiveUser   { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   My edits saving method looks now like this:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel.Data.Customer customer)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           //db.Entry(customer.BaseCustomer).Collection("Users").Load();
           db.Entry(customer.BaseCustomer).State = EntityState.Modified;
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
       ViewBag.CustomerTypeId = new SelectList(db.CustomerTypes, "Id", "Name", customer.BaseCustomer.CustomerTypeId);
       return View(customer);
   }
   ```

The only question remains is how do I access the `Users` navigation property which is null, I've tried to reload it but got an `InvalidOperationException` with error that reads `Member 'Load' cannot be called for property 'Users' because the entity of type 'Customer' does not exist in the context. To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of DbSet<Customer>.` I've also tried to get the Customer again with `Customer baseCustomer = db.Customers.Find(customer.Id);` but then I can't set `db.Entry(customer.BaseCustomer).State = EntityState.Modified;` since it tells me that `An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.` Any ideas, please?

Comment: Create a view model for `Customer` with an addition `boolean` property that you can bind to (and in the GET method, set it to `true` if it meets your condition). But its hard to understand what is the purpose of this. And if there is only one `User`, why do you have `ICollection<User>`?

Comment: I want to allow the administrator to unlock customer's user or to create the user in case a customer doesnt have one from the same place. The action is simply allowing or forbidding the use of self service. And I have collection of users because table of users and table of customers are independent from each other and have separate PKs, so they can't establish a one to one relationship, or at least I didn't find a way to do this, can you advise something?

Comment: Not for the database, but for the UI, a view model is your best option (and that view model could have `public User User { get; set; }` to ensure its only one)

Comment: The model I've posted is for the database which I also used until now for the view. So if I'd do it that way then the accessor would get the first user from the collection and mutator would append changes to this user. Is that what your idea about?

Comment: Cant be 100% sure from your explanation, but if you have a view model containing only the properties you display edit plus `public bool Unlock { get; set; }` then in the GET method, map the data model to the view model and if the data model has one user and `Locked=false`, then set the value of `Unlock` to `true`. Then on post back, check the value of `Unlock` and take appropriate action (I assume by setting `Locked=true` in the database)

Comment: Is there any method(helper or something) used to map the domain model to view model, or it's being done manually?

Comment: tools like [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) can make it easier, but there are others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with creating a dedicated view model that will contain the domain model object(as suggested as second pattern [ASP.NET MVC View Model Patterns by Steve Michelotti](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx)) and an additional property for binding to my check-box. Then in the controller I handle all the logic regarding when to show the check-box selected, and when to create a new user if one not exists. I've encountered several problems so I want to post my solutions, maybe they are far from best-practices but I think they might be of use to beginners, and I definitely would like to see comments or other solutions.

1. Objects aren't persisted if they don't participate in view since EF recreates them on post-back from the data received from the view. This prevented me from adding a `User` property that will be an accessor for the first `User` in navigation collection `Users` property of `Customer` (when I added it, it couldn't access `Users` since this property is null after post-back, as I understood this is because of the recreated `Customer` is detached from context).
2. In order to be able to use navigation properties I had to attach the recreated(by EF, as explained earlier) `Customer` object to the context by setting `db.Entry(customer.BaseCustomer).State = EntityState.Modified;`(thanks to [Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 4: Add/Attach and Entity States § Attaching an existing but modified entity to the context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx)) and to reload the collection by calling `db.Entry(customer.BaseCustomer).Collection("Users").Load();`